# Gradle sync failed: Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.99

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I am stuck on this issue -

```
Gradle sync failed: 
Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.99.
```

I have searched on google but didn't get any solutions, this was not coming yesterday but from today's morning this is giving `Gradle sync failed` issue.

Current version  -

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

**EDITED**

Gradle file -

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.7.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'

//apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'


android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'asdasd'
            keyPassword 'asdasd'
            storeFile file('/home/vikram/Documents/techvalens.keystore')
            storePassword 'asasd'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tv.goin"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 27
        versionName "1.26"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "ID",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "NUM"]


    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            multiDexEnabled true

            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://www.mocky.io/v2\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"ABCXYZ123TEST\"")
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            multiDexEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://www.mocky.io/v2\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"ABCXYZ123TEST\"")
        }
    }
    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // android support libraries
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"


    //Sticky ScrollView
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'

    //One signal Notification
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]'


    //Rating bar
    compile 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'

    //Crash
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'

    //Map
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'


    //Auto Complete
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'


    //multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    //fb
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'

    // font
    compile "uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:$rootProject.calligraphyVersion"

    // network

    //    compile "com.amitshekhar.android:rx2-android-networking:$rootProject.rx2FastAndroidNetworking"

    // image
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$rootProject.glideVersion"

    // parser
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"

    // database
    compile "org.greenrobot:greendao:$rootProject.greenDaoVersion"

    // debug database
    debugCompile "com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:$rootProject.debugDBVersion"

    // dependency injection
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    // reactive
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjava2Version"
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"

    // code generator for view
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.butterKnifeVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.butterKnifeVersion"

    // swipe view
    compile 'com.tubb.smrv:swipemenu-recyclerview:5.4.0'
    compile "com.mindorks:placeholderview:$rootProject.placeholderviewVersion"

    // logger
    compile "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$rootProject.timberVersion"

    // retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'

    //Date Picker
    compile "com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:$rootProject.datepickerVersion"

    //Stripe Payment SDK
    compile "com.stripe:stripe-android:$rootProject.stripeVersion"

    //Qr scanner
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.2'
    compile 'org.zakariya.stickyheaders:stickyheaders:0.7.6'

    //Country code
    compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.0.3'

    // dependencies for local unit tests
    testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.mockitoVersion"
    testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"

    /*New*/
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
    //GLIDE CUSTOM
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'

    //Picasso
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

    //GMS
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'

    //Seekbar

    //    compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'

    //Carousel profile screen
    compile 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1'

    //Auto Scroll
    compile('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    //Swipe RecyclerView
    compile 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'

    //Expandable textview
    compile 'at.blogc:expandabletextview:1.0.3'

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'

    //Image Cropper
    compile 'com.naver.android.helloyako:imagecropview:1.2.0'

    //Expandable RV
//    compile project(':expandablerecyclerview')
    compile project(path:':expandablerecyclerview',configuration: 'default')


    /*

        //Expandable RV
        compile 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
    */

    //Underscore
    compile 'com.github.javadev:underscore:1.28'

    //    compile 'com.lyft:scissors:1.1.1'

    // Include all the Twitter APIs
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'

    /* //Double seekbar
         compile 'com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.util.rangeseekbar:rangeseekbar-library:0.1.0'
     */

    // UI Testing
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.mockitoVersion"
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
}

// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

TOP Level Gradle file -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
//        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.0'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'
    gsonVersion = '2.8.0'
    calligraphyVersion = '2.2.0'
    glideVersion = '4.0.0'

    rx2FastAndroidNetworking = '1.0.0'

//    dagger2Version = '2.8'
    dagger2Version = '2.11'
    rxjava2Version = '2.0.6'
    rxandroidVersion = '2.0.1'
    butterKnifeVersion = '8.6.0'
    greenDaoVersion = '3.2.0'
    placeholderviewVersion = '0.6.1'
    debugDBVersion = '1.0.0'
    timberVersion = '4.5.1'

    //Test dependencies
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
    mockitoVersion = '2.7.1'

    //date Picker
    datepickerVersion = '3.2.2'

    //Stripe Payment SDK
    stripeVersion = '4.1.5'
}
```

Comment: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0. is the latest version so how come it will compile with 11.6.99

Comment: It is quite funny that today these is another question very similar with .99 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831041/gradle-build-error-could-not-find-supportlibrary

Answer (score 1):

Top Level Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
//        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.0'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'
    gsonVersion = '2.8.0'
    calligraphyVersion = '2.2.0'
    glideVersion = '4.0.0'

    rx2FastAndroidNetworking = '1.0.0'

//    dagger2Version = '2.8'
    dagger2Version = '2.11'
    rxjava2Version = '2.0.6'
    rxandroidVersion = '2.0.1'
    butterKnifeVersion = '8.6.0'
    greenDaoVersion = '3.2.0'
    placeholderviewVersion = '0.6.1'
    debugDBVersion = '1.0.0'
    timberVersion = '4.5.1'

    //Test dependencies
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
    mockitoVersion = '2.7.1'

    //date Picker
    datepickerVersion = '3.2.2'

    //Stripe Payment SDK
    stripeVersion = '4.1.5'
}
```

You can remove form your gradle build  file:

```
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]` to `com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.5`

This is how I solved it just now.