# Gradle Build Error could not find supportlibrary

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, onesignal

I'm using support library version 27.0.0
I get this weird build error. The support library I use is 27.0.0 but it still throws error for 27.0.99

I've tried clean project, invalidating caches in Android studio,  restarted my android Studio It did't help.

If I updated my `buildtoolversion` and support libraries to 27.0.2 it still throws error for `27.0.99`

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.99.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.pom
    file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.jar
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.pom
    https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.jar
    https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.pom
    https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.jar
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.pom
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/customtabs/27.0.99/customtabs-27.0.99.jar
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>
```

Iv'e added maven for support library from google

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my default `gradle` config

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.pro.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.17"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

The support library I use is

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'    
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
```

Comment: did you add `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`..???

Comment: @Nilu Yeah I already have it in my gradle file

Comment: @iCoder check selvin comment

Comment: @Selvin Sorry I don't get it. Is there anything I need to change?

Comment: Have you tried google() repository?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi yeah I've tried that too. It didn't help :(

Comment: did you tried 27.0.2?

Comment: Try `implementation` word instead of `compile` and use  `compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2' ` . May it solve problem.

Comment: i am using compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.1.0' and its working fine. try to change ye compile version. because the version 27.0.99 you are trying its not available now in this repo.

Comment: @HemantParmar I'm actully trying to use `27.0.0` which is part of support library. But I landed on this weird error. I tried rolling back to `26.1.0` Nut I get error for `26.1.99`

Comment: @Dharmishtha I think that won't help

Comment: In your case I'll take a look where it come from by `./gradlew app:dependencies` find which one is include this library version.

Comment: @iCoder ok once try to delete app build folder and run it again.

Comment: @TomasIvan Thanks,  from the gradle log OneSignal SDK overrides the support library version to 27.0.99.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OneSignal SDK in your app  ?

If yes,  you should use this include instead :

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.5.8'
```

And you should downgrade your **buildToolsVersion**, **targetSdkVersion** and **compileSdkVersion** to the 26.0.2 and not 27.

It seems to not be 100% compatible with the v27 :)

sources:

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/352
https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/303